# MSSQL 2008R2 Service Broker Initiator Queue Filled With Old Conversations

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server

My initiator queue is filled with about 18 million old messages of either EndDialog or Error message_type_name.

Apparently the Microsoft sample code I used to set up internal activation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281517.aspx) didn't include a step for ending the dialog on the Initiator side (I've read that this is called "Fire and Forget").

I'm wondering, because my sysdercv and other service broker related tables are now into the double digit gigabytes: how can I get rid of these old messages?

I've tried to run END CONVERSATION on several thousand so far, but I'm not seeing any change in size in those system tables.

Additionally, how can I alter the Initiator Service/Queue to automatically EndDialog in the future?

Edit: I should mention that despite more and more messages passing through the pipeline, I haven't seen any of these system tables change size in at least a half hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the tutorial you mention does issue END CONVERSATION from both ends. It therefore doesn't suffer from the "Fire and Forget" pattern. However, the first END CONVERSATION (initiator side) is issued manually from a query window, which is not very practical. In production you'll probably want to have an activated procedure on both ends - the one on the initiator side would receive a reply from the target and end the conversation (that is if you want to keep to the message exchange scheme from the tutorial).

Comment: So if I run something like 
`declare @handle uniqueidentifier 
declare @N int 
set @N = 1 
while @N <= 1000 
begin 
set @handle = (select top 1 conversation_handle from atomicchangesinitiatorqueue with(nolock) where message_type_name = 'schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog'; or message_type_name = 'schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error';) 
END CONVERSATION @handle 
set @N = @N + 1 
END`
 And loop through that on some fixed schedule (i.e. deleting top 1000 at a time) should I expect to see these system tables shrink in size?

Comment: Ugh I apologize for the format of that comment, can't seem to make newlines.